# Выводить сообщение если нет результатов. Если результаты есть - рендерить

Tags: reactjs

Помогите пожалуйста с логикой.

Стейт:

```
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
```

Функция поиска:

```
  function handleSearch(keyword) {
    searchMovie(keyword)
      .then((res) => {
        setSearchResults(res.films);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

Стейт передаю в компонент Main

```
function Main({ searchResults, handleSearch }) {
  return (
    <Box pt='40px' pb='40px' flexBasis='auto' flexGrow={2} flexShrink={0}>
      <SearchForm handleSearch={handleSearch} />

      {searchResults.length ? (
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Movies searchResults={searchResults} />
        </Grid>
      ) : (
        'Ничего не найдено'
      )}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Я хочу следующее:

1. Если поиска еще не производилось то выводить сообщение: "Вы еще ничего не искали"
2. Если результатов нет - выводить сообщение "Ничего не найдено"
3. Если результаты есть, то рендерить их.

Проблема в том, что initial state пустой массив, поэтому при загрузке страницы сразу рендерится Ничего не найдено

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь стэйт загрузки

```
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

в функции загрузки фильмов меняй его на false когда фильмы подгрузились

```
 function handleSearch(keyword) {
    searchMovie(keyword)
      .then((res) => {
        setLoading(false)
        setSearchResults(res.films);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

потом в рендере можешь отображать контент в зависимости от условия

```
function Main({ searchResults, handleSearch, loading }) {
  return (
    <Box pt='40px' pb='40px' flexBasis='auto' flexGrow={2} flexShrink={0}>
      <SearchForm handleSearch={handleSearch} />

      {searchResults.length &&!loading (
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Movies searchResults={searchResults} />
        </Grid>
      )} 
      {!searchResults.length &&!loading && 'Ничего не найдено'}
      {loading&&<Spiner />}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все заработало....только надо было в этом моменте добавить Boolean ...так Boolean(searchResults.length && !loading) т.к. иначе возвращался 0 и если поиском еще не пользовались то он 0 рендерил